# How to assign to a struct pointer in another struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Im having trouble assigning to struct pointer in another struct pointer

The structs looks like this:

#### header.h

```
typedef struct {
    int drawnlines;
    char *name;
} player;

typedef struct {
    char a, b;
    p *mover;
    p *previous;
} lastmove;
```

In another function Im calling another function that is supposed to change a pointer to this struct, this is also the function that gives me an warning:

#### program.c

```
#include header.h
.....
lastmove lmv;
lmv.mover=malloc(sizeof(player *));
lmv.previous=malloc(sizeof(player *));
player p;
p.drawnlines=0;
p.drawnlines=0;
strcpy(p.name, "patrik");
function(&lmv, &p);

.....
int
function(lastmove *lmv, player *p)
{
    lmv->a='b';
    lmv->b='a';
    lmv->previous=lmv->mover;
    lmv->mover=p;        // warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

UPDATE: Now the code works, was a simple mistake. The struct "lastmove" is now changed to

```
typedef struct {
    char a, b;
    player *mover;
    player *previous;
} lastmove;
```

Comment: Do you want to use a cast like `lmv->mover = (p *)p;`,or you just mean  p is 'player'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your code, `mover` is a pointer to type `p`, which isn't defined anywhere - do you mean this?

```
typedef struct {
    char a, b;
    player *mover;
    player *previous;
} lastmove;
```

Also, I think there's an issue with your allocation.  You're allocating enough space for a `player*`, which is a pointer to a player, when what you need is enough space for a `player`.